# How use security on Mifare Ultralight C (using android)?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I am trying to develop an Android application that uses the features (specifically read protection) of the MF0ICU2 tags (Mifare Ultralight C).
That tags are Mifare DESFire EV1 compatible.
Into Android classes, MifareUltralightTag have only standard Read and Write capability, but with transceive method you could send raw command to Tag, for example 0x30 0xYY is a read page and it works.
But how use raw command to use security capability on MF0ICU2 tags?
Does anyone have experience with this type of programming?

Answer (score 0):

You should request the datasheet for the MIFARE Ultralight C tags from the manufacturer. MIFARE Ultralight C tags support different methods of read/write protection. Using the MifareUltralight.transceive() method and javax.crypto.* classes you can construct and send the proper commands.

Comment: I assume you mean a "long PRIVATE data sheet" because this one http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/MF0ICU2_SDS.pdf isn't of much use.

Comment: Yes, it is not available for download. It is reference [8] in http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/MF0ICU2_SDS.pdf