# APDU to change Mifare Ultralight C authentication

Tags: c#, tags, nfc, mifare, apdu

I'm new to NFC programming and wanted to know how I can change the authentication access on a Mifare ultralight C tag.

I mean, can I make the tag write protected with a secret key as I would with Mifare Classic 1k, and then authenticate to write new data again?

There isn't much documentation out there explaining how to do this process...I have a ACR122 card reader to work on this, and I'm using C# to build a windows application.

Any help would be much appreciated, and/or if you have samples codes, that would be awesome.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9234995/1202968

Comment: Ok, so I have to reach the manufacture and ask for the datasheet. I will try to do that...I will follow up on this once I get some answers.

Comment: I posted my answer below

Comment: @user921509 were you able to find/implement any reading/writing functionality for Ultra Light C tags?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post my findings in case someone needs in the future. Although I'm still having problems figuring out how to write protect the Mifare Ultralight C tag temporarly. So in case someone knows how to do it, please let me know. Any sample code would be helpful.

So, found the docs that I needed to get more familiar with the Mifare Ultralight C tag and its security implementation, here are the links in case someones needs it.

http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/1303.pdf, http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/MF0ICU2_SDS.pdf, http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-67-Rev1/SP-800-67-Rev1.pdf,                                        http://www.nxp.com/search?q=137631&type=keyword&rows=10

Comment: It would be more appreciated if there could be some code sample in .net